# EWS not working on Windows Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am currently working on a Windows Azure service and I have to implement the importing of some items from an Exchange server.
Everything works correctly when I test it on the local emulator, I can import the items, but deployed on the cloud it stops working.

This is the exception i get:

> Exception type: ServiceResponseException 
>       Exception message: An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.

The code i use:

```
service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
service.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);
service.Url = new Uri(serverUrl);

itemPropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
itemPropertySet.RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text;

CalendarView calendarView = new CalendarView(fromDate, toDate);
List<ExchangeTask> tasks = new List<ExchangeTask>();
try
{
    FindItemsResults<Appointment> appointments = service.FindAppointments(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, calendarView);

    if (appointments.TotalCount > 0)
    {
        service.LoadPropertiesForItems(appointments, itemPropertySet);
    }
    foreach (Appointment app in appointments)
    {
        tasks.Add(new ExchangeTask() { Name = app.Subject, Description = app.Body, DeadLine = app.End.ToString() });
    }
    return tasks;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

**Edit 1:**
It is not a firewall problem, because if I type the username or password incorrectly than it throws the unauthorized exception, so it connects to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 3 days of pain I resolved the problem. The problem was that I didn't specified the **Time Zone** in the constructor of the `ExchangeService` class. My constructor looks like this now:

`ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time"));`

Answer (score 0):

You should check firewall policy of your VM on Windows Azure